# Empty and Reset database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-2013, localdb

I have a SQL file *EmptyDatabase.sql* to empty and reset my database, similar like this:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable;
.
.
.
DBCC CHECKIDENT (MyTable, RESEED, 0);
.
.
.
```

Now under my connection in the **Server Explorer** I see all kinds of folders like in this picture:
[image]
I would like to know how to store the *EmptyDatabase.sql* under my connection, so I can execute the file whenever I want. Without copying the content in the file and creating a new query under the connection and paste and execute it in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your code in a stored procedure.  Then you just do `EXEC <MyProcedureName>` and it will reset your database.